# New firebase screen black when capture image in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using the updated new firebase Android SDK. I want to send image file to the server. I used firebase storage image upload after captured the image the screen full black and hang how to fix it?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

After image capture result i am getting but it does not show no errors.But black screen.Without firebase it returns image correctly.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap selectedImage = null;
            try {
                selectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(selectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            getImageFromCamera(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where are you using firebase in this code snippet?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing same kind of issue while picking the contact.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37451790/6355890 this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dependency in older fire base and ensure the specific library what  your using and don't use google play services 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0 core it takes the issue.

```
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without more code from your project.  Does this start working again once you remove the upload call or only when you remove firebase dependencies altogether?

The firebase storage quickstart does exactly what you want -- so maybe you can look at that and see if there is some difference between your code and the sample?

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage